# Visual Studio Hangs, Doesn't Launch, Not Responding

Tags: visual-studio

At some point I changed branches via git commands, then when I came back to visual studio it would not load. I closed it, reopened and it never successfully launched. It would try to load the start page, but always end up saying "(Not Responding)" in the windows bar. This is still true even after restarting my machine.

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR: Update Visual Studio**

Next step was to repair installation in "Add or Remove Programs" dialog in Windows 10. Upon which I was notified to update my Visual Studio (to 15.8) before modifying installation. I agreed, and everything is now working again.

The dialog was a little strange, I essentially hit "modify" bottom right, without any options selected. The window said that there was a 0KB change expected, but you still have to proceed to get the option to update.

Good guy Microsoft finding increasingly obnxoious ways to force their user base to update more dependably..

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes